# Too many logs in AndroidStudio

Tags: android-studio, logcat

When I launched my project,
**too many logs occurred** so that I cannot read logs well really I must read.

While I've searched some answer to this problem,

1. I heard that there is a **mini toggle button** at the top of Logcat toolbar.
   *But I cannot find that toogle button anywhere.*
2. I tried **Logcat filter(regex)**,
   *but I think there is some other easy ways to see logs well like Eclipse without doing any hard work.*

Please let me know how to see my own needed logs in Android Studio.